# Configuring DHCP on Juniper junos-vsrx-12.1X47-D20.7-domestic on vmware

Tags: dhcp, juniper-srx, vmware

I'm preparing for JNCIS-SEC exam. I used **junos-vsrx-12.1X47-D20.7-domestic** image to create virtual machine in order to practice for the exam.

I am following [this](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/vsrx/topics/task/configuration/security-vsrx-cli-configuring.html) to configure the vsrx. When I do the following command :

```
set interfaces fxp0 unit 0 family inet dhcp client
```

and after doing `commit` and `show system services dhcp client` I got the following output

[image]

I am trying to create the following topology : 
[image]

The network adapters of the virtual machine are set up as follows
network adapter 1: bridged 
network adapter 2: vmnet 4
network adapter 3: vmnet 5

I am working on a pc which is connected to local area network which uses Juniper switches. The port I am connected to might not be configured as `dhcp-trust`

why I am not obtaining an IP address ??

**EDIT**

The selected answer solved the problem along with the following command :

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet dhcp
```

instead of `dhcp client` in the previous command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are running the SRX stand-alone (eg: not clustered), the first port is `ge-0/0/0`.  It's only when you switch the unit to a chassis cluster member that the interface becomes `fxp0`.

Use:

`delete interfaces ge-0/0/0`

`rename interfaces fxp0 to ge-0/0/0`

`replace pattern fxp0 with ge-0/0/0`

`commit`

and you will be ready to go.

Comment: fxp0 is a management interface.