# faild hardware address for ifd ge-0/0/0 failed on junos-vsrx-12.1X47-D20.7-domestic vmware machine

Tags: dhcp, juniper, juniper-srx, vmware

I have been trying to configure dhcp client on ge-0/0/0, I have asked a question before about it in this [link](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56074/configuring-dhcp-on-juniper-junos-vsrx-12-1x47-d20-7-domestic-on-vmware)

At first the solution provided worked, but when I started the virtual machine again it didn't work.

I tried to trace the error and created a log file using the following commands :

```
 set system services dhcp traceoptions file dhcp_client.dbg
 set system services dhcp traceoptions flag client
 set system services dhcp traceoptions level all
```

Then I used : `show log dhcp_client,dbg` and got the following output:

[image]

The output of : `show system services dhcp client` is :

[image]

As you can see the mac address is 00:00:00:00:00:00

I tried assigning the mac address of the vmware network adapter manually and I got the following error:

[image]

I halted the machine and regenerated the mac of the adapter connecting to ge-0/0/0 but the problem wasn't solved.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post console output as text, not as images.

Comment: @TeunVink I can't copy the console output from the vm machine that's why I posted it as am image

Comment: You can copy the console output. People do it all the time. You can ask about how to do that on [su] or [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching I found that the I gave the virtual machine resources less than what it needs. Once I increased the memory the problem was solved.

More details in this [link](https://forums.juniper.net/t5/forums/v3_1/forumtopicpage/board-id/vGW/thread-id/115).

Comment: Please accept your own answer when possible in two days.